# Continous function $f:Y\to Y$ between quotient spaces

Tags: continuity, quotient-spaces

I was thinking in The following situation. Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y=X/\sim$ with quotient map $q:X\to Y$.
Let $f:Y\to Y$ be a function. Is there an easy way to prove that $f$ is continous provided that $\tilde{f}:X\to X$, a function that makes the same assignment as $f$ is continous $q\circ \tilde{f} = f\circ q$.

I know that, by The universal property of quotient maps, a map $f:Y\to Y$ is continous iff $f\circ q$ but I need to go further. Any suggestion? Is there a general result?

Comment: If $\tilde f$ (which need not be uniquely determined by $f$) is continuous, then $f$ is continous. This follows from the universal property applied to $q\circ\tilde f$.